# IBM DB2 ODBC driver 64bit fails to load

Tags: db2, odbc

When I try to connect to the DB2 database with the 64bit DB2 ODBC driver, the API call fails. With 32bit driver its fine.

Here is the code:

```
TCHAR dsn[] = _T("DSN=ODBCDB2"), connStringOut[100] = _T("");
SQLSMALLINT connStringOutSize = 0;
SQLRETURN rc = SQLDriverConnect(connHandle, NULL, (SQLTCHAR *)dsn, _tcslen(dsn), connStringOut, sizeof(connStringOut) / sizeof(TCHAR), &connStringOutSize, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

//rc = -1
//Error message: Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1, C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLIO.DLL)
```

> Environment Details:
>
> - IBM DB2 v11.5.0.1077
> - IBM DB2 ODBC Driver v11.5.0.1077 (32-bit)
> - ODBC v3.8
> - VC++ (Visual Studio 2017)
> - Windows 10 64-bit

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you run the 32 and 64 bit code? Are there any other changes? What is the runtime environment for the app?

Comment: Thanks data_henrik! I have added a DSN in 32bit and 64bit "Data Source Administrator" dialog. Then built and run the application in 32bit and 64bit mode (for debug and release).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the cause of the problem:

When a DSN is added using "ODBC Data Source Administrator", some entries in the registry get created. One of the entry is:

```
[Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI]
Driver REG_SZ C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLIO.DLL
```

For 64bit DSN, the correct DLL is **db2cli64.dll**.

Don't know why despite using the "64bit ODBC Data Source Administrator" to create the DSN, the DLL in the registry is the wrong one.

Comment: That depends on *which* Db2 driver(s) got registered with the Microsoft ODBC driver manager by earlier actions, and which one of those drivers you selected with the GUI of odbcad32.

Comment: Thanks mao!  That's "IBM DB2 ODBC Driver". And the file name under this is "DB2CLIO.dll". The installation was with all default settings.

Comment: we cannot tell from your question *exactly* what you installed and how, and what actions you took after installation. I used the "ODBC and CLI" driver (v11.5 64-bit Win10 1903 x64), and after configuring db2dsdriver.cfg and db2cli.ini and running its db2cli install -setup, the odbcad32 picked up the correct driver and it loaded without issue.  Exact details are essential if you have a symptom that others cannot recreate.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. You must change the default DLL in registry.
Enter **regedit** **HKEY_CURRENT_USER-> Software-> ODBC-> ODBC.INI -> *{Name of your DS}***

Change value **Driver** from **DB2CLIO.DLL** to **DB2CLI64.DLL**