# Connecting to DB2 using Python and ODBC Driver

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to connect to DB2 using python 3.10.2 (x64).

I am able to setup connection using ODBC (Windows 11 x64, odbcad32).

I am using VS Code IDE for python.

When i use below code i am getting error-

```
import pyodbc
connectionDB = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DATA_SOURCE_NAME')
```

InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1, C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLIO.DLL). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: I am able to setup connection in ODBC driver, while testing connection in ODBC i get connected successfully in ODBC

Comment: Not enough facts in your question. Are you running python directly at the cmd.exe shell, or from powershell, or from some IDE?  Give details. What is the MS-Windows version and bitness and codepage(regional settings)?  What is the python version?  How did you install ibm_db (by which command-lines) and what is its version?  When you connect with odbc, do you mean with ms odbcad32 GUI, or with isql?

Comment: Please answer __all__ the questions

Comment: Python Version --- 3.10.2

Comment: @mao, PLease find the answers of all your questions-
Are you running python directly at the cmd.exe shell, or from powershell, or from some IDE? -- VS code
What is the MS-Windows version and bitness and codepage(regional settings)? --- I am using Windows 11, 64 bit
Python version --- 3.10.2
How did you install ibm_db (by which command-lines) and what is its version? --- I am using ODBC Driver, I have not installed ibm_db
When you connect with odbc, do you mean with ms odbcad32 GUI, or with isql? -- GUI

Comment: You already have a Db2 driver installed (in c:\Program Files...\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN).   Please run its `db2level` command at the cmd command line, and __edit your question__ to include the plain text output of the `db2level` command. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030097/ibm-db2-odbc-driver-64bit-fails-to-load